# Error during rate app

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, windows-store

In my app 
http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/app/1rm/d8639e5b-93ae-4d34-a575-d84e205c134d

I get an error message when users press submit after rating.

Get error c101a006.

Not sure why this happens, open store but not able to submit review

As far as I can see no rating can be submitted due to error, at least not on Windows 8 machines running more than one account. How can I verify rating works now on machines running one account?

Comment: Gotta love Microsoft oldschool error codes.

Answer (score 5):

It is ZEST_E_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, an error that tells you that the Store server suffered a heart-attack when trying to process the submission.  The rating page itself is displayed by the Store app on your machine.  I had no trouble myself submitting a rating for your app.

So this has nothing to do with your app itself.  Web server errors happen, they can take a few days to get resolved.  At least from my test it is clear that the server can no longer be the problem.  If you still have trouble then there's something wrong with your Microsoft account.  Login on [this web page](https://account.live.com/) and double-check that your birthdate and home country have been entered.

Answer (score 3):

Without any code it's difficult to say.

Anyway searching googling the error code I went to [Microsoft support site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2781172/en) That says it's a server error, for example when account data are not completed. It's hard to do more with only these informations.

Answer (score 1):

My friend was getting the same error since he was from Siberia and this is how Microsoft responded to him. Its mainly caused when one tries to rate an app while the app marketplace aint supported in that region.

1. Go to settings > region and language > change the phones region to a supported country > restart the phone (change to UK preferably)
2. Go to http://support.xbox.com/en-US/billing-and-subscriptions/account-management/change-region and click on Account migration
3. Sign in with your xbox account (in some cases they will send you verification code on email address which you added before)
4. Finish account migration to UK (in my case). Please keep in mind that they allow you to do this only ONCE per 3 months
   Problem solved. Try to download free apps or games and everything will work.

Solution for application which requires payments:
1. Go to settings > region and language > change the phones region to a supported country > restart the phone 
2. Go on store. Find some game or application for payment.
3. Add payment option which you wish

Enjoy and cheers :) 
Note 1: I suggest you to complete account migration on Xbox from other device (PC/Mac)
Note 2: Xbox region restriction was cause of this error